# Setup network printer with 2 routers (modem-router and wireless-router )

Tags: printer, network-printer

I have a network printer (HP Office Jet 6000), I want to setup this printer in my network.

This is my network structure:

ISP --> Modem (10.0.0.2) --> WIFI (LAN: 10.0.0.3, WAN: 192.168.0.1) --> Printer (192.168.0.254)

Modem: Draytek Vigor 2950

WIFI: TP-LINK TLWR841N

How can I print from network 10.0.0.x?

Comment: I don't see two modems in your description and I think the WIFI information inverts LAN and WAN.

Comment: Do you mean 2 routers (your modem being a modem-router)?

Comment: Sorry because of wrong description. I mean 2 router, one is modem-router, one is wireless-router

Comment: Do you know which port is used on your printer?  If not, what's the model number for reference?

Comment: Thank you, I did it. My printer using port 9100. I try to NAT port 9100 on two router and it works now.